# Program is ignoring one line of input

Tags: c, input, newline, c99, fgets

Here is some code I'm using to create a struct from user input:

```
    // make a new branch from user input
branch usr_input_branch() {
  char main_text[INPUT_MAX_SIZE];
  char b1[INPUT_MAX_SIZE];
  char b2[INPUT_MAX_SIZE];
  char response[4];

  do {
    printf("Enter main text: ");
    fgets(main_text,INPUT_MAX_SIZE,stdin);
    if ((strlen(main_text)>0) && (main_text[strlen (main_text) - 1] == '\n'))
        main_text[strlen (main_text) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Enter Option 1: ");
    fgets(b1,INPUT_MAX_SIZE,stdin);
    if ((strlen(b1)>0) && (b1[strlen (name) - 1] == '\n'))
        name[strlen (name) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Enter Option 2: ");
    fgets(b2,INPUT_MAX_SIZE,stdin);
    if ((strlen(name)>0) && (name[strlen (name) - 1] == '\n'))
        name[strlen (name) - 1] = '\0';

    puts("Here is your branch:");

    branch br = brCreate(b1,b2,main_text);
    brPrint(br);

    printf("Is this OK? [Y/n] ");
    scanf("%s",response);
    int doLoop = 1;
    do {
      if (tolower(response[0]) == 'y')
      {
        return br;
      }
      else if (tolower(response[0]) == 'n') {
        doLoop = 0;
      }
      else {
        puts("Invalid response.");
        printf("Is this OK? [Y/n] ");
    scanf("%s",response);
      }
    } while (doLoop);
  } while (1);

  // inaccessible code
  error("Inaccessible code",0);
  return brCreate("","","");
}
```

This is the output I want:

```
Enter main text: stuff1
Enter Option 1: stuff2
Enter Option 2: stuff3

Here is your branch:
stuff1
Option 1: stuff2
Option 2: stuff3
```

However: Here is what happens:

```
Enter main text: Enter Option 1: stuff
Enter Option 2: stuff1
Here is your branch:


Option 1: stuff

Option 2: stuff1
```

It appears that it completely ignores the first thing and moves straight to the second thing. What should I do to remedy this?

I'm using gcc with c99 in case that affects anything.

Comment: Probably you need to skip the preceding newline. (E.g. `scanf("%s",response);` : Newline remain as inputs. )

Comment: You also haven't provided the code for `brCreate` or `brPrint`, which are important code paths for reproducing your problem. [MCVE]'s must be minimal, but they must also be complete and reproducible, which this is not.

Comment: Side note: simplify `if ((strlen(name)>0) && (name[strlen (name) - 1] == '\n'))
        name[strlen (name) - 1] = '\0';` --> `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: brCreate and brPrint are simple: https://pastebin.com/LYLEJRtd

Comment: +BLUEPIXY I was using scanf but it ignores spaces